# Selecting rows of matrix by value of first column

Tags: matlab, select, matrix

Let's say I have a matrix `A`, whose first column are IDs, and a vector `B`, containing certain IDs in a random order (and some of them might be missing etc).
How do I select the rows of `A` with matching IDs in the order given by `B`?

**Example**:

Using the matrices

```
A = [2, 0.4, 0.3;
     9, 0.2, 0.8;
     3, 0.3, 0.4;
     5, 0.1, 0.5];
B = [9; 2; 5];
```

I would like to get the matrix

```
C = [9, 0.2, 0.8;
     2, 0.4, 0.3;
     5, 0.1, 0.5];
```

Comment: @knedlsepp I think the linked question's answer(s) might solve it with `sorting` needed thereafter. Of course, this is assuming OP here wants to use the vector as an indexing array.

Comment: Ok maybe it wasn't so clear.
A contains two columns, one is an ID, the other one is a value.
B just contains ID in a certain order.

B doesn't contain the index I want, but the Ids I want

Comment: @Flos Check out the posted solution then? Think you want something like that?

Comment: if you don't care about the order:
`A(ismember(A(:,1),B),:)`
----
if you do care about the order and the size of B is fixed to 3
----
`A([find(A(:,1)==B(1)), find(A(:,1)==B(2)), find(A(:,1)==B(3))],:)
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the revised stated problem, the first column of `A` are the `IDs` and `B` also contains certain `IDs` and we need to match `A`'s `IDs` with those of `B`'s and select the matching rows from `A`. Based on such an assumption, you can few approaches here.

**Approach #1 [ With `ismember`]**

```
[~,idx] = ismember(B,A(:,1))
C = A(idx,:)
```

**Approach #2 [ With `bsxfun`]**

```
[idx,~] = find(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),B'))
C = A(idx,:)
```

**Approach #3 [ With `intersect`]**

```
[~,~,idx] = intersect(B,A(:,1),'stable')
C = A(idx,:)
```

Comment: didn't know about sortrows. nice :)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I actually need to keep the same order as in B i.e. if B is [3; 1; 4], I need [3, 1; 1, 2; 4, 6]
I kind of need to add the right value in the B vector next to the right ID, without changing any order

Comment: Just perfect :)
Didn't know that ismember also return the indices :)
Thanks you :)
PS: it gives the C matrix in 11seconds, with for loop, 35minutes... (My A matrix is huge)

Answer (score 2):

If your IDs are **unique, positive integers**, you could do the following:

**Approach #4 [ With `sparse` and indexing]**

Construct a sparse vector that corresponds to the mapping: `ID -> rowIndex` and evaluate this vector:

```
indexOfID = sparse(A(:,1), 1, 1:size(A,1));
C = A(indexOfID(B),:);
```

This could be beneficial, when you want to query your IDs more than once, as you only have to build `indexOfID` once.
(Also I do like the syntax of the "function evaluation" `indexOfID(B)`)

Comment: This is also working, but I actually have much more columns in A, and I didn't find a way to make it work easily with several columns :( (not used to use sparse matrix)
But thanks anyway :)

Comment: It's nice you are maintaining the IDs of the approaches :) It's nice on Stackoverflow, we flood OPs with varieties of approaches! It's good for them and its good for us answerers!

Comment: @Divakar: Well, consistency is key! ;-) [Still it makes me realize that this might not be the best idea, as others might change their answers at some point later in time. Well, nevermind...]